# RXJS combineLatest operator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to use combineLatest operator and getting bit beard response, when I am changing the interval duration for first and second observable

When I am Using following -

```
let intObs1$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(3));
    let intObs2$ = interval(500).pipe(take(3));
    combineLatest([intObs1$, intObs2$,]).subscribe(([intObs1, intObs2]) => {
      console.log(intObs1, intObs2);
    })`
```

output on console is as follows -
0 0
0 1
1 1
2 1
2 2

Whereas when I am using changing it bit -

```
 let intObs1$ = interval(500).pipe(take(3));
    let intObs2$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(3));
    combineLatest([intObs1$, intObs2$,]).subscribe(([intObs1, intObs2]) => {
      console.log(intObs1, intObs2);
    });
```

output on console is as follows -
1 0
2 0
2 1
2 2

Can anyone please explain why second script is not emitting the Zero/Zero as initial value ??

Answer (score 2):

The documentation explains this.  `combineLatest` waits for EVERYBODY to emit before it returns anything at all.  If one of the inputs generates multiple values before the second one starts, the early ones are lost.  With your timing, it's just random chance whether that happens.  You could run that multiple times and get different results.

https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest